# Default text file permissions?

Tags: permissions, text

How do I find out the default permissions for a newly created text file? I've tried

```
ls -l filename.txt
```

but it keeps saying to me that it cannot access the txt file, so I'm pretty sure that I'm doing it wrong. I've gone over notes and googled but I can't find out how to look at it's default permissions.

Comment: Can you please include the error message you are receiving? Either you do not have access to run `ls` in the directory you are in, or the file you want to `ls` does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, specifically its saying ls: cannot access filename.txt: No such file or directory. But i created the text file using vi filename.txt

Comment: @jestermonkey the file is not created until you save in `vi` (`:w`)

Answer (score 0):

As jordanm stated in a comment above, `vi` does not write a file until you use the write command `:w`.

If you are unsure how to write the file, I would recommend creating a file with either `touch filename.txt` or `>filename.txt`. Now you can see the default permissions of a newly created file with `ls -l filename.txt`

Answer (score 0):

What controls the default permissions is known as the `umask`.

BUT....

It depends on how the file was created, because various daemons can be configured to use a different default `umask`.  So creating a file by a samba/cifs share, or via sftp, or by logging in interactively and using `touch` or creating a new file by saving in some text editor like `vi` or `joe` or whatever can all end up with different permissions, even if the files are created by the same user in the same directory.

In the same vein, there is also the ownership of files/directories created.  The system default is probably the owner is the creating user and the group is the creating user's primary group.  But be aware that other file permissions can affect this (ie, the `setgid` bit on a directory) as well as various daemon configuration options just like the `umask` setting.

Answer (score -2):

Write

```
ls -l
```

And you will see, something like:

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 username username     4096 lip 28 01:20 filename.txt
```

The values may of course differ, and there likely will be a many lines like these for different files. What you look for is the drwxr.... information which tells you about permissions.

[Here](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/help/chmod.html) you have their meanings.

Comment: the key word in the question here is *default* permissions, not *resulting* permissions.